# Quality Factor Formula

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, analog, oscillator, resonance

I read on many books this formula to calculate the quality factor of a series between a resistance and a reactive component (L and/or C):

[image]

Now let's consider the series between a resistance and a capacitance:

[image]

In this case the capacitive reactance is equal to -1/(ωC), so according to the previous formula, Q should be negative. But everywhere it is written as a positive quantity. So my question is: should the formula in the first picture have the absolute value? So Q = |X|/R?

Comment: series LRC and parallel LRC have useful Q factors. These circuits can store energy, as long as the circuit has a closed-path for current to circulate and thus the energy changes from magnetic to capacitive energy. We call this "resonance", or "resonating" or "circulating", and requires both inductance and capacitance.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I think that comment is irrelevant to the OP’s question.